# Proper way of emitting an event from a function - Node JS - Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Assume that I have two files.

`server.js`

`test.js`

server.js have all the initialization codes in place (Mongoose, Express..etc). It also has the below code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

In my test.js file, I have something related to mqtt. It is irrelevant, however, please understand that I don't have any variable access in there (req, app). Because that file isn't part of the route or anything.

It is included in server.js as:

```
require('test.js');
```

I am not getting into any details of MQTT or how it works. Consider that one or more functions inside test.js is running on a specific time. So, when ever that happens, how can I emit an event using socket.io from the test.js file?

My client side dashboard is ready to receive the event. I am just confused how to design the system, especially how to access the `io` variable which exist in `server.js` file.

Comment: `io.sockets.emit("something")` ?

Comment: I want to do something like that from `test.js`, but I don't have access to `io` variable inside `test.js` :) Hope you get it.

Comment: Could you use the [Event Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to send an event to `server.js` which then emits?

Comment: You could require your server package and socket.io again in test.js, since they are singletons, the methods used should work the same way

Comment: If you're exporting a function from `test.js` you can give it a parameter which is the `io` variable. Then in your `server.js` you can require `test.js` as a function, and pass the io variable to it. Then just run it. `const test = require('test')(io)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already just export a function from test.js that takes `io` as a parameter:

```
  module.exports = function test(io) {
    io.on("connection", socket => {
      socket.emit("greeting", "hello world!");
    });
 };
```

From your server.js you just have to pass in the argument:

```
 require("./test.js")(io);
```